# Remove duplicate rows from 2d array, but preserve rows with non-empty value in a specific column

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates, grouping

I have a 2d array containing rows where a user might be represented more than once.  I need to remove duplicate instances of user data, but I don't want to lose any meaningful data in the process.  Rows with a non-empty value in the `Flying Tour` column should be prioritized over a row with an empty value in the same column.

Sample data:

```
$data = [
    [
        'Access ID' => 12345,
        'Registration Date' => '2018-02-27',
        'First Name' => 'Damian',
        'Last Name' => 'Martin',
        'Flying Tour' => ''
    ],
    [
        'Access ID' => 12345,
        'Registration Date' => '2018-02-27',
        'First Name' => 'Damian',
        'Last Name' => 'Martin',
        'Flying Tour' => 'Yes going'
    ],
    [
        'Access ID' => 789456,
        'Registration Date' => '2018-03-27',
        'First Name' => 'Ricky',
        'Last Name' => 'Smith',
        'Flying Tour' => ''
    ],
    [
        'Access ID' => 789456,
        'Registration Date' => '2018-03-27',
        'First Name' => 'Ricky',
        'Last Name' => 'Smith',
        'Flying Tour' => 'Two way going',
    ],
    [
        'Access ID' => 987654,
        'Registration Date' => '2018-04-27',
        'First Name' => 'Darron',
        'Last Name' => 'Butt',
        'Flying Tour' => ''
    ]
];
```

My code:

```
$results = [];
      foreach($data as $input){

      $isDuplicate = false;
      foreach($results as $result){
        if(
            strtolower($input['First Name'])===strtolower($result['First Name']) &&
            strtolower($input['Last Name'])===strtolower($result['Last Name'])      &&
            strtolower($input['Registration ID'])===strtolower($result['Registration ID']) &&
            strtolower(!empty($input['Flying Tour']))
        ){
            //a duplicate was found in results
            $isDuplicate = true;
            break;
        }
      }
      //if no duplicate was found
      if(!$isDuplicate) $results[]=$input;
}
```

Desired result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Access ID] => 12345
            [Registration Date] => 2018-02-27
            [First Name] => Damian
            [Last Name] => Martin
            [Flying Tour] => Yes going
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Access ID] => 789456
            [Registration Date] => 2018-03-27
            [First Name] => Ricky
            [Last Name] => Smith
            [Flying Tour] => Two way going
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Access ID] => 987654
            [Registration Date] => 2018-04-27
            [First Name] => Darron
            [Last Name] => Butt
            [Flying Tour] => 
        )

)
```

Some changes are made please see

Comment: _Flying Tour_ for Darron Butt ought to be empty. Ricky Smith instead should have _Flying Tour_ as _Two way going_.

Comment: What you ask for, and what you show us you want, is contradictory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `foreach()` along with array keys to check for duplicates:

```
$results = [];
foreach ($data as $input) {
    if (!isset($results[$input['Access ID'] . '_' . $input['First Name'] . '_' . $input['Last Name']])) {
            $results[$input['Access ID'] . '_' . $input['First Name'] . '_' . $input['Last Name']] = $input;
    } else {
        if ($results[$input['Access ID'] . '_' . $input['First Name'] . '_' . $input['Last Name']]['Flying Tour'] == '') {
            $results[$input['Access ID'] . '_' . $input['First Name'] . '_' . $input['Last Name']] = $input;
        }
    }
}

$results = array_values($results);
//array_multisort( array_column($results, "First Name"), SORT_ASC, $results );
echo "<pre/>";
print_r($results);
```

Sample Output: https://3v4l.org/2KcSN

Answer (score 0):

The point here is that for the first run, `$results` is still empty. Thus, the whole logic that can set `$isDuplicate = true` never runs for the first instance.

This means that for the first record, `$isDuplicate = false` and thus it will always be added.

Furthermore, `strtolower(!empty($input['Flying Tour']))` is a bit weird... and should give an error in my opinion (even if it doesnt...)

You should move the `!empty($input['Flying Tour'])` outside the for loop, since it does not need the current values in the new array for its check. This will solve the problem.

```
if(!$isDuplicate && !empty($input['Flying Tour'])) $results[]=$input;
```

If you want to learn and improve your code, have a look at [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) it is made for this purpose: filtering array results.

--edit

```
foreach($results as $id => $result){
    if(
        strtolower($input['First Name'])===strtolower($result['First Name']) &&
        strtolower($input['Last Name'])===strtolower($result['Last Name'])      &&
        strtolower($input['Registration ID'])===strtolower($result['Registration ID']))
    ){
        // Check if the $results value for Flying Tour is empty
        // if yes: update its value $results[ $id ]['Flying Tour'] = $input['Flying Tour'], but still mark as duplicate(!)

        //a duplicate was found in results
        $isDuplicate = true;
        break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: if(!$isDuplicate && !empty($input['Flying Tour'])) $results[]=$input;
 was good but what happend it return only those value that having Flying Tour

Comment: if there is no value it should return those value too

Comment: ah, now I get it. What you want is to check on the 3 values, if they are the same as the one in $results already (you got that part). Then, you also want to check if the value in `$results` currently has no value for `Flying Tour`. If that is the case, you want to update that record with the new value in `$input`. Though, still mark that record as duplicate, else it will show up twice...

Comment: Thank you all specially @Oluwafemi Sule

Answer (score 0):

Compose a key from values that should be unique.

If the composed key from each loop array doesn't exists in `$results` include it in the results.

Also if composed key exists and `Flying Tour` value is empty replace with new array.

```
$results = [];

foreach ($data as $input) {
    $key = implode([
        $input['First Name'], 
        $input['Last Name'], 
        $input['Access ID']
    ], '-');

    if (array_key_exists($key, $results) 
        && !empty($results[$key]['Flying Tour'])) continue;

    $results[$key] = $input;
}

var_dump(array_values($results));
```

Answer (score 0):

Uses `foreach` to iterate over `$data`. Storing duplicates info via `$duplicates` variable, and using it to remove duplicate values.

**Alternative:**

```
$duplicates = array();
$results = $data;

foreach( $results as $k=>$v ) {
    if( isset( $duplicates[$v['Access ID']] ) ) {
        unset( $results[$k] );
    }
    else $duplicates[$v['Access ID']] = TRUE;
}

print_r( $results );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<pre>';
$data = array_reverse($data);
$combined = array_map(function($row){

    $row = array_map('trim', $row);
    unset($row['Flying Tour']);
    //print_r($row);exit;
    return array_reduce($row, function($v1,$v2){
        return $v1 . "|" . $v2;
    });
}, $data);

$uniqueElements  = array_unique($combined);

$uniqueIndexes = array_keys($uniqueElements);
$newData = [];

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if(in_array($key, $uniqueIndexes)){
        $newData[] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrayvalues = array();   // Set the array before foreach 
foreach( $res as $key=>$value ) {
    if( isset( $arrayvalues[$value['Access ID']] ) ) {   // Here checking the Array value and $value are same
        unset( $res[$key] );            // unset the array key value here
    }
    else $arrayvalues[$value['Access ID']] = $value['Access ID'];      // If it is not it will display here and returns true.
}


$i=0;
$testvalues = array();   // Set the array before foreach 
foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
    print_r($value);
    $arr[$i] = $value;
    $testvalues[$i]=$arr[$i];

    // unset($arr[$key]);
    $i++;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($testvalues) ;   // Get the respective out put here
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

To group by unique users, you only need to reference their unique access number.  Use that value as grouping first-level keys in the result array.  As you iterate, if there is no saved row for the access id, then save the row.  If the row exists, but the `Flying Tour` value is empty, then save the current row in its place.  When finished iterating, you can remove the associative first-level keys by calling `array_values()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/WZNoG))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
    if (empty($result[$row['Access ID']]['Flying Tour'])) {
        $result[$row['Access ID']] = $row;
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```